# cron job in cpanel not working for laravel scheduler

Tags: laravel, cron, scheduling

I have a query in `kernel.php` for scheduling in Laravel. when i run command

> php artisan schedule:run

it works great. in the host i defined a cron job as :

> /usr/local/bin/php /home/username/sub-folder/artisan schedule:run >
>   /Dev/null 2>&1

and this is my example:

```
$schedule->call(function (){
    $user = User::where('username' , 'john')->first();
    $user->username = 'bob';
    $user->save();
});
```

My Laravel project is in the sub-folder.It's not doing any thing!What am i doing wrong?

Comment: you need to make sure the shared hosting enable `proc_open` .. else its not working

Comment: how can i be sure of that ???

Comment: you need to ask the technical support to enable it for you.. for my exp, they dont want to open it because of security reason..

Comment: in this case what can i do for Laravel scheduling?

Comment: solution.. use digital ocean or other available platform..